# Identify Story: A boy uses a knife to transport himself to another world

Tags: story-identification, magic

Or another time. I don't quite remember, having read it about 7-10 years ago.

All I remember is a boy that uses a knife to sort of create a magical portal in the air in  front of him, by feeling like he is the edge of the knife. He travels between our world and another, or perhaps our time and another time, but I'm pretty sure it's another world. I remember him getting chased once and having to hurry up with the "portal cutting", and I think he had company that time.

Comment: Then when he's in a hurry he breaks it. It was my favourite when I read it (14 years old), then I tried to read it not too long ago (when I was 20) and couldn't.

Comment: @Frank You couldn’t – why? Too boring?

Comment: For me and now, yes, the story was too slow.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170081/a-book-about-travelling-to-hell-and-cutting-worlds-with-a-knife (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73280/fantasy-book-series-about-people-who-are-accompanied-about-animals-representing (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 45):

Sounds like Philip Pullman's [*The Subtle Knife*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Subtle_Knife). It's part of the His Dark Materials series. In it, a character called Will uses a knife to make portals between parallel worlds.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Best book in the trilogy.

Comment: @JMD Are you nuts? The best one was the first one, by far.

Comment: Yup, this is it.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ, totally serious! Though to be fair I read them out of order. I read the Subtle Knife as a early teen several times without ever knowing it was part of a trilogy. Then I read the first and third books. The first book is obviously amazing, but the golden compass (telling the future) is nothing compared to the power of ripping across dimensions to a young boy in need of adventure!

Answer (score 15):

Oh, boy oh boy. I read this book over a decade ago...

It's "[*With My Knife*](http://andrewlansdown.com/fiction/novels/with-my-knife/)" by Andrew Lansdown.

The portals are based on the shapes he cuts

There are dragons.

The knife is a dragon knife.

Comment: I'm curious to see which answer will be chosen by the OP.

Comment: so, this book predates the subtle knife by quite a bit?

Comment: According to the two cited links, yeah.. I guess mine does.

I haven't read the subtle knife, but I saw this question pop up and it immediately reminded me of "with my knife"

Comment: Yes! I read this book as a kid, too. I immediately thought of it as soon as I read the question title. This is the one where he peels potatoes and they turn into super-strong and super-fast stones, right?

Comment: Yes, potato stones. He carves three dogs, throws one in the fire and one in the river because they're poor carvings. The third shows up on his doorstep and the poor people in the other world comment that one dog drowned, one dog burned alive, and a third ran away. The cardboard from the doorway he first creates is so heavy in the new world that they use a train of horses to drag it...