# Fantasy book series about people who are accompanied about animals representing their "soul"

Tags: story-identification

It's a series of fantasy books in which the inhabitants of the world, from the time when they're children, get to somehow have an accompanying small animal that represents their soul or their personality.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the [His Dark Materials](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44427-his-dark-materials) series by Philip Pullman. Each character has an individual ["Dæmon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A6mon_%28His_Dark_Materials%29) that supposedly represents a sort of spirit animal.

Per wikipedia:

> A dæmon is a type of fictional being in the Philip Pullman
>   fantasy trilogy His Dark Materials. Dæmons are the external physical
>   manifestation of a person's 'inner-self' that takes the form of an
>   animal. Dæmons have human intelligence, are capable of human
>   speech — regardless of the form they take — and usually behave as though
>   they are independent of their humans. Pre-pubescent children's dæmons
>   can change form voluntarily, almost instantaneously, to become any
>   creature, real or imaginary. During their adolescence a person's dæmon
>   undergoes "settling", an event in which that person's dæmon
>   permanently and involuntarily assumes the form of the animal which the
>   person most resembles in character. Dæmons and their humans are almost
>   always of different genders.

Comment: No offense meant to the OP, but: It's almost too obvious! Like someone saying "Trying to ID a story about a short person who saves the world by putting a magic ring into a volcano. I think the ring turns you invisible." :)

Comment: @Lexible - All questions are easy if you know the answer :-)

Comment: @Lexible I honestly didn't knew the answer. Some one just told me about it today, and I really wanted to read it, but realized I couldn't remember the title but at all.

Comment: @ShivanDragon No worries! An again, no offense meant. Richard is very correct. I am just clumsily trying to communicate my amusement. The series is a good read, and I hope you enjoy it. (I've read it three or six times.)

Comment: @Lexible I've read it twice: once as a child and once later.  It's entertaining in completely different ways depending on age.

Comment: And the book "The Golden Compass" in the series was made into a film of the same name.

Comment: Darn you beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

It might be *[Spirit Animals](http://spiritanimals.scholastic.com/about)*. It fits what you are looking for. In it, children at the age of 11 get to drink a magical mixture which summons a spirit animal. I loved it very much.

[image: Cover of first book]

Partial summary from the Wikia page for [the first book](http://spiritanimals.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Born):

> Enter the world of Erdas, where every child who comes of age must discover if they have a spirit animal, a rare bond between human and beast that bestows great powers to both. A dark force and forgotten lands, and has begun an onslaught that will ravage the world. Now the fate of Erdas has fallen on the shoulders of four young strangers . . . and on you.

It has children who have animals associated with their inner soul or personality, although it does not happen to everyone, and most of these are not small animals.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange. This doesn't answer the question. Might I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions here? We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: The question here is tagged [tag:story-identification], which means the asker was looking for a *particular* series they read, rather than for recommendations. It was also already answered correctly over a year ago.

Comment: I requested Rand al'Thor to undelete the answer, and added some more to it to flesh it out, because I think this could be useful for people looking for similar books in the future.