# A book about travelling to hell and cutting worlds with a knife

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the title of a book, actually a series (probably a trilogy).

I just have a few memories - I read it 20+ years ago but the book is contemporary. The few things I remember:

- the two main characters (boy and girl) come from different worlds which are copies one of each other - one of them being dystopian (if I recall correctly)
- one of the characters (the boy I think) can move from world to world by "cutting a hole" in thin air with a knife
- they travel at some point (by the end of the series) to Hell when they need to do something to save the worlds

The end is

> sad. The two characters fall in love but for some reason they cannot cross the world borders anymore (this is a decision they make for the good of the worlds) and they "meet" on a bench which is in both worlds and imagine the other one being on his/her bench as well.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73280/fantasy-book-series-about-people-who-are-accompanied-about-animals-representing (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is the [His Dark Materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials) trilogy by Philip Pullman, in particular the second and third books: *The Subtle Knife* and *The Amber Spyglass*.

The first book focuses solely on the girl, Lyra. The boy, Will, is introduced at the start of the second book, and he acquires the titular Subtle Knife which allows them to travel between worlds during the course of that book.

> the two main characters (boy and girl) come from different worlds which are copies one of each other - one of them being dystopian (if I recall correctly)

Lyra (the girl) and Will (the boy) both come from Oxford, but in two totally different worlds. Will's world is (assumed to be - I don't recall if it's ever explicitly stated) our own, and is set in a modern setting.

Lyra's world is, in many ways, less technologically advanced (they use zepellins to travel, have no cars, etc.). However, they also have "daemons", which are external representations of the person's soul; when the person is young they can switch forms, but will eventually settle on a single form. They have some element of autonomy, but they're limited in how far away from their "master" they can travel.

They first meet in a third world that, if I remember correctly, has portals to several worlds, including both Will's and Lyra's.

> one of the characters (the boy I think) can move from world to world by "cutting a hole" in thin air with a knife

This is the Subtle Knife referenced in the title of the second book. It's obtained by Will during the course of that book, and he's taught how to sense places in the fabric of the world(s) where he can make a "cut", creating a portal between worlds.

> they travel at some point (by the end of the series) to Hell when they need to do something to save the worlds

In the third book, they travel to the "Land of the Dead". The trilogy is [considered by some people to be anti-religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials) (specifically anti-Christianity), so it has a lot of religious elements and themes in it, so recalling this as Hell is likely.

> The end is sad. The two characters fall in love but for some reason they cannot cross the world borders anymore (this is a decision they make for the good of the worlds) and they "meet" on a bench which is in both worlds and imagine the other one being on his/her bench as well.

There's a prophecy that Lyra is the "second Eve", and the primary goal of one of the book's antagonists is preventing Lyra's "sin" (falling in love, though possibly also having sex). In the third book she falls in love with Will, but - I believe - the Subtle Knife is broken (possibly on purpose), trapping them in their own Oxfords.

Comment: As usual with story ID's can you suggest details form the books that support the various plot points. The OP may have confirmed this is the right book but other users that aren't so sure may like to see more details and not have to go through the links.

Comment: @Edlothiad Absolutely, I'm in the process of editing now. It's been about ten years since I last read the books myself, so having to do a fair amount of research to confirm what I am and am not remembering correctly (as well as trying to avoid spoilers as much as possible).

Comment: You may not be aware, but we have a meta post that highly encourages spoilers on story-id questions as the user is expected to have already read the book.

Comment: @Edlothiad I don't recall seeing that meta post, so yes, I was unaware. I still think we need to strike a balance between providing enough evidence to convince the OP (and other readers) that the answer is correct, without also completely ruining the book(s) for those who *haven't* read them but decide they want to after reading the question and its answers.

Comment: Of course, and that seems entirely reasonable, hence the usual "cover the points they remembered with snippets from the text" recommendation. Which usually prevents most spoilers and is *usually* good enough to convince the OP

Comment: IIRC the knife was broken by accident earlier than the end of the book (when Will is distracted while using the knife) and is later repaired. The decision to remain in their worlds was informed by the fact that existing in the "wrong" reality slowly causes one's health to degenerate. I can't remember if the knife was destroyed again though.

Comment: @detly also they can't just leave the windows open (which is how Lyra found Will in the first place - through a window he had opened before he knew how to close them) because bad spirits come through the gaps left by the windows.

Comment: @stannius Additional correcting on the ending: leaving a window open slowly sucks the life out of the multiverse.  The multiverse generates enough life energy or whatever on its own to leave no more than one window open, so they leave one window open to allow souls to escape hell.  They can't stay in each others' worlds, lest they sicken and die.  And they can't briefly create temporary windows, because each time you open a window it creates a monster somewhere.  Exactly calibrated to give the characters an upsettingly unhappy ending.  >:(

Comment: @Erhannis I forget why they had to leave one window open? How did souls get to hell before the subtle knife was created?

Comment: @stannius I kinda forget, too; I think they just went there?  And they used the subtle knife to get them out an reunite them with nature or something.  It does seem like there's something I'm forgetting, though, about how they ended up in hell.

Comment: @stannius, They didn't leave the window to let souls _in_ to hell.  They left it to let them out.  It wasn't exactly Christian hell.  It was more like ancient Greek hell--a gloomy, underground place where nothing ever happens.  Once the window out of hell was opened, souls could leave, whereupon they would kind of dissipate, and merge with the cosmos.

Comment: The first two books were pretty good, but the third book got really weird and depressing. It was very much an "anti-narnia"

Comment: @pojo-guy, I dunno...Narnia's ending is pretty sinister.  Ever read "The Problem of Susan"?

Comment: Narnia is specifically and deliberately an allegory of core Christian doctrine. Free will and consequences of choices are as much a part of Christian doctrine as heaven and redemption. I will have  read "The Problem of Susan", and find its premise silly. Susan was not lost because she discovered sex, she was lost because she deliberately put superficial  and transient things (fashion in her case, which is story line believable in a post ww2 teenaged girl) ahead of the deeper truths she had experienced. .

Comment: Given that the questioner has accepted this answer (and there can be no doubt anyway), should this Q be tagged [his-dark-materials], or is that frowned upon in identification questions?.

Comment: @PJTraill Not sure what the general consensus is on that, but personally it doesn't seem to have any great value. The primary purpose of tagging is to help people find questions about the work, but I can't see anybody who is interested in His Dark Materials (and who is already aware of it) benefiting from having this question included in the tag.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Will does indeed break the knife on purpose at the end of the last book.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I suppose you are right that there is not much benefit, and indeed it would presumably just clutter up the tag. I had wondered whether to ask on meta, but I suppose there is not much point.

Answer (score 25):

As Alex k. said in the comments, this is [His Dark Materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials) trilogy by [Philip Pullman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Pullman)

The individual books are

1. Northern Lights (The Golden Compass in North America) (1995)
2. The Subtle Knife (1997)
3. The Amber Spyglass (2000)

It matches every detail you've included in your question.

> It follows the coming of age of two children, Lyra Belacqua and Will
>   Parry, as they wander through a series of parallel universes. The
>   three novels have won a number of awards, most notably the 2001
>   Whitbread Book of the Year prize, won by The Amber Spyglass. Northern
>   Lights won the Carnegie Medal for children's fiction in the UK in
>   1995. The trilogy took third place in the BBC's Big Read poll in 2003.
>
> The fantasy elements include witches and armoured polar bears, but the
>   trilogy also alludes to ideas from physics, philosophy and theology.
>   The trilogy functions in part as a retelling and inversion of John
>   Milton's epic Paradise Lost, with Pullman commending humanity for
>   what Milton saw as its most tragic failing, original sin. The
>   series has drawn criticism for its negative portrayal of Christianity
>   and religion in general.

The first book "The golden compass" was dramatised in the 2007 movie of the same name
[image]